# ANGULAR when a property 'x' is private->error "cant use outside 'y' component because x is private" but when it is public it shows x don't exist in y

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-ui-router, angular-httpclient

i m using angular 9
and following this angular course on cousera, this is the instructions that i m trying to implement
https://www.coursera.org/learn/angular/supplement/SPNU5/exercise-instructions-angular-http-client

i had read a lot of blogs posts before asking but unable to find a solution.

when i updated the constructor of my menu.ts file with

```
constructor(private dishservice:DishService,
    @Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL) { }
```

and menu.html file with

`<img height="200px" src="{{ BaseURL + dish.image }}" alt="{{dish.name}}">`

it shows this error

```
ERROR in src/app/menu/menu.component.html:12:33 - error TS2341: Property 'BaseURL' is private and only accessible within class 'MenuComponent'.

12     <img height="200px" src="{{ BaseURL + dish.image }}" alt="{{dish.name}}">
                                   ~~~~~~~

  src/app/menu/menu.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MenuComponent.
```

and then when i make baseURL public it shows

```
 error TS2339: Property 'BaseURL' does not exist on type 'MenuComponent'.

    12     <img height="200px" src="{{ BaseURL + dish.image }}" alt="{{dish.name}}">
                                       ~~~~~~~

      src/app/menu/menu.component.ts:7:16
        7   templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component MenuComponent.
```

my json server is working fine

```
F:\json-server>json-server --watch db.json -d 2000

  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/dishes
  http://localhost:3000/promotions
  http://localhost:3000/leadership
  http://localhost:3000/feedback

  Home
  http://localhost:3000

  Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
  Watching...
```

here are the complete code of my app module.ts,dishservice.ts,menu.ts and menu.html file.

app-module->

```
///... are module related to material design
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
...
import{HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
...

import {DishService} from './services/dish.service';
import { PromotionService } from './services/promotion.service';
import { LeaderService } from './services/leader.service';

import 'hammerjs';
import{baseURL} from './shared/baseurl';
import { DishdetailComponent } from './dishdetail/dishdetail.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
   ...
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [DishService,
              PromotionService,
            LeaderService,
            {provide: 'BaseURL', useValue: baseURL}
          ],
  entryComponents: [
              LoginComponent    
              ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dishservice.ts->

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Dish} from '../shared/dish';
import {Observable,of} from 'rxjs';
import {delay} from 'rxjs/Operators';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseurl';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DishService {
  getdishes():Observable<Dish[]>{
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL+'dishes');
  }
  getDish(id: String): Observable<Dish> {
  return this.http.get<Dish>(baseURL + 'dishes/' + id);
  }
  getFeaturedDish(): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes?featured=true').pipe(map(dishes => dishes[0]));
  }
  getDishIds(): Observable<string[] | any>{
    return this.getdishes().pipe(map(dishes => dishes.map(dish => dish.id)));
  }
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
}
```

menucomponent.ts->

```
import { Component, OnInit , Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Dish} from '../shared/dish'
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseurl';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  dishes:Dish[];
  constructor(private dishservice:DishService,
    @Inject('BaseURL') BaseURL) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dishservice.getdishes().subscribe(dishes => this.dishes=dishes);
  }
}
```

```
<div fxFlex *ngIf="dishes"><mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="200px">
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let dish of dishes" [routerLink]="['/dishdetails',dish.id]">
    <img height="200px" src="{{ BaseURL + dish.image }}" alt="{{dish.name}}">
    <mat-grid-tile-footer><h1>{{dish.name | uppercase}}</h1></mat-grid-tile-footer>
</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>

</div>
```

i m new to all this pls help

Comment: Can you check if the BaseURL coming up in console.log inside ngOnInit() ?

Comment: the console log for the menu page says status code 400

Comment: curious! try this `public BaseURL; constructor(private dishservice:DishService,
    @Inject('BaseURL')  BaseURL) { this.BaseURL = BaseURL}`

Comment: yes its the link to the json server ```export const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/';```

Comment: Just a moment.. Aren't you creating an injection token for baseURL ?

Comment: yes i m thx for the help @RPasha and @Akhil the problem is solved by ```public BaseURL; constructor(private dishservice:DishService,     @Inject('BaseURL')  BaseURL) { this.BaseURL = BaseURL} ``` but i dont get it why it is happening in the first place

Comment: arent the template file is connected to typescript  to use its property

Comment: @user11813160, I'm not sure what was exact problem, but I guess the problem is in using `@Inject` in constructor. btw i would appreciate upvote ;)

Comment: can u suggest a better way of doing the same thing

Comment: Can't you just declare the variable as public in the constructor instead of private?

Comment: @David i had also tried that in the constructor in that it shows ```BaseURL doesnt exist``` the details and exact error code is given in the question itself

Comment: You mean that you added the `public` keyword right? I got confused because your complete code did not show that.

Comment: @David i removed the private keyword in the other execution so that by default it will become public and it throw the error that the ```BaseURL doesn't exist```

Comment: That's not how it works on a constructor. Without an access modifier such as `public` or `private` it behaves differently and must be separately declared. So "no access modifier" != "public"

Comment: `baseURL` instead of `BaseURL`. It's case sensitive.

Comment: @kokogino I tried baseURL as well it's of no use

Comment: @Deborahk if I don't specify the access modifier type then by default it has to be something public,private or protected so the error is like that the property of  'x' type so it can't be accessed but the error says that the Base url doesn't exist in the ts file